# Executing Java utility via Autosys job returning ORA-02396, running it manually works fine

Tags: oracle, unix, autosys

I'm using 3rd party Java utility in Unix server which connects to SaaS application and create there new items.

Running it manually from Unix server is completing successfully.

Executing it from Autosys job on the same server resulting with an error:

> "ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time"

This is **only on first run** - when running it again from Autosys, it completing successfully.

The failure is **immediate**, it's strange to be connected to idle_time issue as it fails so quickly.

Any suggestions what can cause this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [a known issue with autosys](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/124881/de-service-fails-due-to-ora02396.html). The vendor recommends to alter the db user profile with IDLE_TIME set to UNLIMITED.

The issue is that Autosys always keeps a connection pool with 2-4 idle connections to the database. So if you run it and it's been a couple hours since the last run, you'll get a timeout error.

If your company security policy doesn't allow unlimited idle timeouts, you may need to come up with a workaround, like setting up an autosys job which connects to the database e.g. every hour and runs any kind of query to keep the connection alive.